# Cannot read property length of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am trying to simply check if I have an empty input text box but I get this error when I run this in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Here is how I go about doing it.  I check for DOM readiness and then call the function:

```
function walkmydog() {
    //when the user starts entering                                                                                                                                                
    if(document.getElementById('WallSearch').value.length == 0) {
        alert("nothing");
    }
}

if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", walkmydog, false);
}
```

Comment: Can you please attach the relevant part of your HTML?

Comment: Are you sure `WallSearch` is the ID of the `input` element? If it was, you would not get that error: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/x9Vf2/

Comment: How do you check for DOM readiness?

Comment: i've added the code i used to check for DOM readiness and i am sure that the id is "WallSearch". The function is getting called but  it errors out

Comment: The error means that what ever element is returned by `getElementById('WallSearch')`, it does not have a `value` property. *Every* form field has a `value` property, hence it seems it does not return the right element. Please post your HTML or create a http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: Felix you were right. i did not have an id for the input box.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The id of the input seems is not `WallSearch`. Maybe you're confusing  that `name` and `id`. They are two different properties. `name` is used to define the name by which the value is posted, while `id` is the unique identification of the element inside the DOM.

Other possibility is that you have two elements with the same id. The browser will pick any of these (probably the last, maybe the first) and return an element that doesn't support the `value` property.

Answer (score 10):

perhaps, you can first determine if the DOM does really exists,

```
function walkmydog() {
    //when the user starts entering
    var dom = document.getElementById('WallSearch');
    if(dom == null){
        alert('sorry, WallSearch DOM cannot be found');
        return false;    
    }

    if(dom.value.length == 0){
        alert("nothing");
    }
}

if (document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", walkmydog, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to throw out another simple solution to this problem.

```
if(dom?.length !== 0){
// Referred to as optional chaining 
// this checks if the array is empty or if a value exists 
}
```